# How to concatenate two strings and omit possible duplicate word?

Tags: java, string, replace, concatenation

I have two strings and I want to concatenate them in a way that a resulting duplicate first/last word should only appear once.

*Examples:*

```
String s1 = "hello world";
String s2 = "world am waiting";
String res = "hello world am waiting"; // result with only one 'world'

String s1 = "call attested";
String s2 = "attested with level A";
String res = "call attested with level A"; // result with only one 'attested'
```

How do I concatenate the two strings and omit a possible duplicate word as seen above?

Comment: What did you try? What algorithm would you use to tell a human what to do? What should happen if s2 was `"hey world, I am waiting"`?

Comment: This **is not** a duplicate of simply concatenating two strings. The word `world` is present in `s1` and `s2` but only desired once in `res`.

Comment: am expecting result as "hello world am waiting" with s1 and s2 .
how i need to concatenate them

Comment: Is this the only condition, where the last word of s1 and first word of s2 is the same?

Comment: Can you provide more examples?

Comment: @Matt  yes, i need to replace if ending of s1 and starting of s2 are same i need mke it as only one word

Comment: @pcsutar String s1 = "call attested" String s2 = "attested with level A";
for these Strings i need result as "call attested with level A"

Comment: Check this out . this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_concat.asp

Comment: also you need to split the last word if s1 and first word of S2 . check if both are same.  if yes. java provides direct utility function to remove that and contact remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the last word in `s1` and the first word in `s2`. If these words match, you omit one of them while concatenating.

For this, you can write a method like this:

```java
private static String specialConcat(String s1, String s2) {
    String lastWord = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
    String firstWord = s2.split(" ")[0];
    if (firstWord.equals(lastWord)) {
        return s1 + s2.substring(lastWord.length());
    } else {
        return s1 + " " + s2;
    }
}
```

Here are some test cases including edge cases:

```java
Assert.assertEquals("hello world am waiting",
        specialConcat("hello world", "world am waiting"));

Assert.assertEquals("call attested with level A",
        specialConcat("call attested", "attested with level A"));

Assert.assertEquals("", specialConcat("", ""));
Assert.assertEquals("hello", specialConcat("hello", "hello"));

Assert.assertEquals("hello world", specialConcat("hello", "world"));
Assert.assertEquals("hello world", specialConcat("hello world", "world"));
Assert.assertEquals("hello world", specialConcat("hello", "hello world"));
Assert.assertEquals("abc abcde", specialConcat("abc", "abcde"));
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, You solution will fail for test case: ```assertEquals("hello Prashant, How are you?", specialConcat("hello Prashant, How are you?", " How are you?")); ```

Comment: @pcsutar The requirement per comments on the question is to remove a duplicate **word** not *phrase*. Therefore, I'm not sure if this is a valid test case.